# Evaluate the integral $\int\frac{1}{2+3\sin x}\,\text{d}x$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Please evaluate the integral,

$$\int \frac{1}{2+3\sin x}\,\text{d}x.$$

What I have tried is to substitute $\sin x = \sqrt{1-x^x}$ but I was stuck in a maze. Also, I did look a the wolfram solution. Can anyone propose a different solution from Wolfram, perhaps simpler with a bit of explanation?

Comment: My question is very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1248875/integral-of-int-frac153sinxdx#1248875

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

Use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), $$\tan\frac x2=t$$

$$\implies\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$  and $$\frac x2=\arctan t\implies dx=\frac{2\ dt}{1+t^2}$$

Comment: that is wolfram's solution. any other solution?

Comment: @arashaga, $$\int\frac{dx}{2+3\sin x}=\int\dfrac{\sec^2\dfrac x2\ dx}{2(1+\tan^2\dfrac x2)+3\cdot 2\tan\dfrac x2}$$ set $\tan\frac x2=t?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee why does the denominator has the $\tan$ expressions (in the comment)?

Comment: OK, I got the denominator, but now I don't get the numerator, shouldn't it be just $2$?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to this [link](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100203225723AAMmis3) to answer your question. It is almost exactly similar with your question. I hope this helps.

Comment: That is wolfram solution I asked for a different solution if there is any.

Comment: :appreciate your help but Please kindly read my question again. Specifically the bottom part "I did look ta the wolfram solution. Can anyone propose a different solution from Wolfram, perhaps simpler with a bit of explanation?". I looked at your solution it is exactly what  lab bhattacharjee offered and it is the same as wolfram's solution. However, it appears that it is the only solution so far unless you tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

use Weierstrass substitution: $\sin\left(x\right)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, where $t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$
$⇔2\arctan\left(t\right)=x$**,**$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{2+3\sin\left(x\right)}
$$$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}}{2+3\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)}
$$$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{2dt}{2t^2+6t+2}
$$$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t^2+3t+1}$$
$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{\left(t+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}}$$

substitute $t+\frac{3}{2}=u$
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{du}{u^2-\frac{5}{4}}$$
now we need another substitution:$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}u=v,\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}⇔du=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}dv$

$$\frac{4}{5}\int_{ }^{ }\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}dv}{v^2-1}$$

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan\left(v\right)+C$$
undo substitution $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}u=v$, we have:$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}u\right)+C$$

undo substitution $t+\frac{3}{2}=u$, we have:$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan\left(\ \frac{2\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)+C$$
we're done.

Answer (score 0):

write sin x as 2*sin (x/2)*cos(x/2) and divide numerator and denominator by cos^2(x/2). Then substitute tan(x/2) for t,complete perfect square in the denominator(there will be a constant as well).final answer will be (2*tan inverse(2*tan (x/2)+3))