# Evaluating $ \int \frac{1}{5 + 3 \sin(x)} ~ \mathrm{d}{x} $.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> What is the integral of: $\int \frac{1}{5+3\sin x}dx$

My attempt:

Using: $\tan \frac x 2=t$, $\sin x = \frac {2t}{1+t^2}$, $dx=\frac {2dt}{1+t^2}$ we have:

$\int \frac{1}{5+3\sin x}dx= 2\int \frac 1 {5t^2+6t+5}dt $

I'll expand the denominator: $5t^2+6t+5=5((t+\frac 3 5 )^2+1-\frac 1 4 \cdot (\frac 6 5)^2)=5((t+\frac 3 5)^2+0.64)$. So:

$2\int \frac 1 {5t^2+6t+5}dt = \frac 2 5 \int \frac 1{(t+\frac 3 5)^2+0.64}dt=\frac 2 5(\frac 5 4\arctan((t+\frac 3 5)\frac 5 4))=\frac 1 2 \arctan(\frac{5t+3}{4}) $

But if I'll place $\tan \frac x 2=t$ I won't be able to simplify it further and since the online calculator's answers don't have $\tan \frac x 2$ there, I believe I made a mistake. What is wrong with what I did and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your method seems absolutely correct to me! What answer does the online calculator give?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas http://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%285%2B3sinx%29 

Now I see that my answer is actually almost identical... I was probably looking at something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

From what you got on that calculator, use the following identities to simplify it:

- $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$
- $1+\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x/2)$

You'll see that the results are same.

Comment: I prefer setting $ \sin(x) = \frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}} {2} $ then complete the square.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, note that I'm still a junior in math and you're one of the top guys. I use elementary methods, you use special methods. There's a reason why I consider you as epic. :3

Comment: I was trolling, there's no need to complicate the integral by introducing complex numbers when it's no required. A simple [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) should suffice.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, What makes you think that I wasn't trolling too? :3

Comment: Challenge Master Note: Well Played.

Comment: @GohP.iHan, btw, do you even use Facebook now? I sent you a friend request ages ago. :3

Answer (score 0):

Its very likely that the expression was simplified further from $\tan(x/2)$ as that expression has many identities, hence why its revered for its integral substitution properties. Also, your answer is correct. Your method is very brute force, but if you know what your doing, your not overkilling the problem *that* much.

Answer (score 0):

Taking from 
$5t^2$+6t+5, instead of expanding, complete the square.

=5(t+$\frac{6}{10})^2$-$\frac{16}{5}$

Rewrite in the form

=$\frac{-1}{5}$$\int$$\frac{1}{16/25-(t+6/10)^2}$

=$\frac{-1}{5}$[$\frac{5}{4}$$tanh^{-1}$($\frac{t+6/10}{4/5})]$+C

=$\frac{-1}{4}$[$tanh^{-1}$($\frac{5t}{4}$+$\frac{3}{2}$)]+C

Still getting answer in terms of tan(x/2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner evaluation
\begin{align}
& \int \frac{1}{5 + 3 \sin x}dx\\
=& \int \frac{\sec x}{5 \sec x+ 3 \tan x}dx
= \int \frac{5 \sec^2 x+ 3 \sec x\tan x}{(5 \sec x+ 3 \tan x)^2}dx\\
= &\int \frac{d (5 \tan x+ 3 \sec x)}{(5 \tan x+ 3 \sec x)^2+16}=\frac14\tan^{-1}\frac{5 \tan x+ 3 \sec x}4
\end{align}